# How to test if a variable is referencing a number in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

Simple Question: How to test if a variable is referencing a number in coffeescript? Could not find an answer in the [docs](http://coffeescript.org/).

Comment: I think you can try to use this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric ```isNumber: (n) -> not isNaN(parseFloat(n)) and  isFinite(n)```

Comment: I dont understand `not isNaN(parseFloat(n) and isFinite`. Shouldn't your method return some value to the method caller?

Comment: Hmm it's a function :) Could you explain please what's wrong?

Comment: Did not know that you can ommit `return` in coffeescript. Anyhow, your function typecasts a String to a Number, thus it is worthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can test variable type (which seems to be what you're asking) with

```
typeof n is 'number' and isFinite n
```

Note that this doesn't convert strings, etc., just checks straight up whether it's already a finite number.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against using libraries, underscore/lodash provide great utility functions.

[_.isNumber](https://lodash.com/docs#isNumber)
or
[_.isFinite](https://lodash.com/docs#isFinite)
(depending on if you want `Infinity`, and `NaN` to be categorized as numbers)

Answer (score -1):

You can have a global function:

`isNumber: (n) ->
  return not isNaN(parseFloat(n)) and isFinite(n)`

and use it:

`is_number = isNumber('123')`

it returns `true` if argument is not NaN and is not a `infinity`. Otherwise returns `false`

Comment: typecasts strings. bad func